# cmd - Find and copy specific files (from a list) along with their full path

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, find, copy

I have a list of file names (list.txt) in format:

```
...
wfplwfs.sys.mui
wide.EaseOfAccess.png
wide.Holographic.png
Windows Proximity Connection.wav
...
```

I want to find these files within a directory with sub-directories and copy them with their full path to a destination directory.

I read many similar articles here and tried many examples but with no luck so far.

I tried below similar code found in another thread

```
@echo off

set src=D:\LTSC-new\W10UI\LTSC-updated-2103\install-0\Windows\WinSxS
set dest=%~dp0copied
set file_list=%~dp0for_SFC.txt

if not exist "%dest%" mkdir "%dest%"

pushd "%src%"
for /f %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do (
 for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%src%" ^| find /i "%%a"') do
  xcopy /hrkvy "%%b" "%dest%"
 )
)
pause
```

but it does nothing.

Please help?

Comment: Put `echo "%%a"` as first command in your outer `for` loop. Does it list the file names correctly (no unexpected spaces, weird characters etc.)?

Comment: and what about `('dir /b /s "%src%\%%a"')` ?

Comment: for /f %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do echo %%a  lists the files correctly

Comment: Does `for /f %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do echo "%%a"`? (I had a reason to include the quotes; you wouldn't be the first to have unintended trailing spaces in the file)

Comment: echo "%%a"  lists the files in quotes;  echo %%a  lists files also but without quotes.  BTW I noticed files with spaces in their name are not listed correctly - only first word is listed

Comment: the last issue can easily be solved: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do ...`

Comment: Can you provide a few lines of `for_SFC.txt` (edit it into the question - don't put them in a comment)

Comment: lol - sorry for not spotting it earlier: you forgot a `(` after the second `do`. (btw: giving a "Syntax Error" isn't exactly "it does nothing")

Comment: done.  BTW  for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do (for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%src%\%%a"') do xcopy /hrkvy "%%b" "%dest%")  works but files are copied without keeping folders structure as I want to be.

Comment: SOLVED! My final script which did the job is>      for /f "delims=" %%a in ('type "%file_list%"') do (title processing "%%a" & for /f %%b in ('dir /b /s "%src%\%%a"') do robocopy "%src%" "%dest%" %%a /copyall /dcopy:dat /s)